# How do i keep the old value number of int variable and change the form1 size according to the number of rows?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is working code for me:

First in the top of the form1:

```
int firsttime;
private const int ROW_SIZE = 22;
private int NumberOfRows;
Image ima;
private System.Timers.Timer _refreshTimer;
private int _thisProcess;
```

Then in the constructor:

```
firsttime = 0;
dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
dataGridView1.Columns["Column2"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
dataGridView1.Columns["Column3"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

In the form1 load event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _thisProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
            InitializeRefreshTimer();
            PopulateApplications();
        }
```

Then the timer init method i use the timer to update the processes list and the dataGridView1.

```
void InitializeRefreshTimer()
        {
            _refreshTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            _refreshTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;
            _refreshTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerToUpdate_Elapsed);
            _refreshTimer.Start();
        }
```

The timer elapsed event:

```
void TimerToUpdate_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateApplications();
        }
```

The PopulateApplications method:

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();            
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
                {
                    var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                    ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                    ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
                    ima.Save(@"c:\temp\ima.jpg");
                    String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima,p.ProcessName, status);
                }
            }
            firsttime += 1;
            if (firsttime == 1)
            {
                NumberOfRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            }
            if (NumberOfRows != dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
            {
                int diff = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - NumberOfRows;
                this.Height = this.Height + (ROW_SIZE * diff);
                NumberOfRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            }

        }
```

The resize image method:

```
public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
        {
            return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
        }
```

In the form1 designer i added dataGridView1 with 9 columns just for the test.
In the designer the form1 size is: 652, 358
The dataGridView1 size is: 624, 479

Now each time a new row is added the form1 Height resize automatic by += 22.
If a row is removed that's mean if i close any app/process it will automatic update the dataGridView1 and remove one row also the form1 will resize automatic.

Checked it with the program Paint. Opened it closed it few times and it worked.

Comment: Use another variable?

Comment: New value `int old = -1;` and in the loop `if(old = -1) { old = i;}` or something like that ?

Comment: Remember `int` variable doesn't give you `Length` property. You have to convert it to string.

Comment: re: Use another variable? 
Yeah, a variable which is higher in scope than your executing code.

Comment: Edited my question im not sure if im doing it right. Since i want to change the form1 size according to how many rows removed or added each itertion. If in second itertion added more new 5 rows and then next itertion removed 3 rows then first add 5 rows then removed 3. And allways remove the last one/s that have been added.

Comment: If the size of the row is 22 make it `this.Height += 23`. I think this is because the border takes 1 pixel.

Comment: Ok i found a solution to what i wanted . I will update my question with what i got os far.

Comment: Please don't update your question with the answer. This is a Q&A site - not an A&A site. You need to keep your question as a question and then, if you have your own answer, add it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I have replaced my original answer with the following code because it is better.  You do not need both `lastValue` and `currentValue` variables.  Instead I have used a variable called `NumberOfRows`.  I have also added 2 constants `ROW_SIZE` (the amount added to the hight of the form for each row) and `BaseFormHeight` (the height of the form when there are no rows).

```
private const int ROW_SIZE = 22;

private int NumberOfRows;
private int BaseFormHeight

void PopulateApplications()
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
        {
            ... add a row to the data grid ...
        }
    }

    if(NumberOfRows != dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
    {
        NumberOfRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        this.Height = BaseFormHeight + (ROW_SIZE * NumberOfRows);
    }
}
```

In the `Load` event handler you should record the initial height of the form and the initial number of rows.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NumberOfRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    BaseFormHeight = this.Height - (NumberOfRows * ROW_SIZE);

    PopulateApplications();
}
```

Comment: Ben where do i update first time the lastValue didn't got it sorry ? If im using your code now as it is it will first itertion enter the IF statement and thne currentValue is 9 and lastValue is 0 so it will do 22 * 9 and that resize the form.

Comment: @user3681442 I imagined that you were storing `lastValue` and `currentValue` as private class variables.  In fact `currentValue` would be better as a local variable.  I was trying to keep my code similar to your question so you could see where the changes were, but it is not very well organised so I will edit it to make it better.

Comment: Ben the problem now is that first itertion/loop Rows.Count is 9 and NumberOfTows is -1. So it's entering the if and then it's doing 22*9 thats 198. And in the original the form1 size height is 358. The original size in the beginning should be as it is and then only to resize according to if rows added or removed.

Comment: Ben in the line: if (NumberOfRows != dataGridView1.Rows.Count) after first loop/itertion there are 9 rows and numberofrows is 0. then in the end the Height of the form change to 546.  I did all you changed. Still it dosen't keep the original size of the form in the first loop since there are 9 rows and numberofrows is 0 they are not the same so it's entering and resize the form.

Comment: @user3681442 You need to understand the concept that I am suggesting and apply it to your situation.  This is your work and because I can not see your code I am having to make a lot of guesses.  Why do you have 9 rows in the dataGrid before PopulateApplications is called the first time?  Where did these 9 rows come from?  Are there other method that are adding rows?  Also, make sure you have the Load event registered correctly.

Comment: `NumberOfRows` will be initialised with the number of rows that the form has when the Load event if called, if this is 0 then NumberOfRows will be 0 to start with.  But really this is not important.  The most important part is making sure that `BaseFormHeight` and `ROW_SIZE` are set correctly.

Comment: Ben i don't have 9 rows only 9 columns. But at the first time when its making the loop the foreach there are 9 processes running so it's adding 9 rows inside the loop. Then when it finish the first loop first time and making the IF statement out the loop there are already 9 rows.

Comment: Ben i explained what happen and added the full code. The dataGridView1 adding 9 rows in the first loop it could be also add 20 rows or just 2 depending on how many processes are running at the time im running my program. So if there are 9 rows its ok with how the form size is now 652, 358 and from here in each next itertion of the foreach if it will add another rows resize the form1 height according to how many rows have been added or removed. Could be i closed a process so now there are only 8 processes so now it should resize down the height -= 22 .

Comment: Another option is not ot resize the form automatic but to add columns on the side so i can scroll up down and see the rows added. For example in the beginning there are 9 rows if there are more then 9 make/create columns on the side for scrolling up down. But i want to solve first the automatic form resize problem.

Comment: Also the dataGridView1 size is: 624,479 i just dont want to show the emptyp art of the datagridview thats why i want the form1 to resize automatic according to how many rows are added or removed.

Comment: This is a link to the form1 designer.cs code where also the dataGridView1 is: http://pastebin.com/ZmGEmFnF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55092/discussion-between-ben-and-user3681442).

Answer (score 0):

This is working code for me:

First in the top of the form1:

```
int firsttime;
private const int ROW_SIZE = 22;
private int NumberOfRows;
Image ima;
private System.Timers.Timer _refreshTimer;
private int _thisProcess;
```

Then in the constructor:

```
firsttime = 0;
dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
dataGridView1.Columns["Column2"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
dataGridView1.Columns["Column3"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
In the form1 load event:

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _thisProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
            InitializeRefreshTimer();
            PopulateApplications();
        }
```

Then the timer init method i use the timer to update the processes list and the dataGridView1.

```
void InitializeRefreshTimer()
        {
            _refreshTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            _refreshTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;
            _refreshTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerToUpdate_Elapsed);
            _refreshTimer.Start();
        }
```

The timer elapsed event:

```
void TimerToUpdate_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateApplications();
        }
```

The PopulateApplications method:

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();            
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
                {
                    var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                    ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                    ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
                    ima.Save(@"c:\temp\ima.jpg");
                    String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima,p.ProcessName, status);
                }
            }
            firsttime += 1;
            if (firsttime == 1)
            {
                NumberOfRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            }
            if (NumberOfRows != dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
            {
                int diff = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - NumberOfRows;
                this.Height = this.Height + (ROW_SIZE * diff);
                NumberOfRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            }

        }
```

The resize image method:

```
public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
        {
            return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
        }
```

In the form1 designer i added dataGridView1 with 9 columns just for the test. In the designer the form1 size is: 652, 358 The dataGridView1 size is: 624, 479

Now each time a new row is added the form1 Height resize automatic by += 22. If a row is removed that's mean if i close any app/process it will automatic update the dataGridView1 and remove one row also the form1 will resize automatic.

Checked it with the program Paint. Opened it closed it few times and it worked.